# Eliminating for loops in Matlab

Tags: matlab, for-loop, vectorization

Here's a simple question.  The following nested for loop creates an array of sine-wave values.

```
N = 2^16;
for m = 1:10;
    for i = 1:N
        sine(m,i) = sin(2*pi*i./(8*2^m));
    end
end
```

It seems like I should be able to create this array without the use of the for loops, but I've tried various syntaxes and always get an error message.  Thanks in advance for any insights.

Comment: Please consider accepting the solution that best solved the case for the question, though it would be hard to choose one I think, given all these are quality solutions here.

Answer (score 6):

You could use `bsxfun` like this:

```
sine = sin(bsxfun(@times, 2*pi*(1:2^16), 1./(8*2.^(1:10))' ));
```

Comment: Instinct tells me that Dan's would be faster although I'd be curious to see a timed comparison... Sadly I don't have matlab to hand.

Comment: I am afraid your instinct is wrong. On my computer, `bsxfun` is over 4 times faster. (Although I dont care much about timing when it is takes less than a tenth of a second.)

Comment: You could suggest this too - `sin(bsxfun(@rdivide, 2*pi*(1:2^16), (8*2.^(1:10))' ));`

Comment: Oo, that is interesting, I thought the vectorized version would fit Matlab's optimisation better. Thanks for running the comparison!

Comment: Good point Divakar. (And just to be sure @n00dle: I said that "your instinct is wrong", but this is not ment to be offensive. I just wanted to indicate that the situation happens to be contrary to your instinct. I can more or less express myself in English, but I am not a native speaker.)

Comment: Don't worry, I wasn't offended :) I took it in the spirit in which it was intended.

Comment: Make jokes, go your corridor but. I am crazy Henkie not so I draw me there delicious nothing from on. (I challenge you to make sense of that ;) Its real Dunglish.)

Comment: I know from the hat and the edge :P

Answer (score 5):

Try the following:

```
ii = 1:2^16;
m  = [1./(2.^(1:10))].'% transpose

prefactor = 2 * pi / 8;

sine = sin(prefactor * m * ii);
```

I perform a matrix multiplication `A*B`, in which a is a column vector size nrows, and B is a row vector size ncols, the resulting matrix will be of size nrows x ncols. Therefore `m` is a column vector and `ii` a row vector.

Answer (score 4):

Try using `ndgrid`

```
N=2^16;
[M, I] = ndgrid(1:10, 1:N);
sine = sin(2*pi*I./(8*2.^M));
```

Comment: Thanks to all of you.  Learning about bsxfun() is very worthwhile.